# What type of address returned on applying ampersand to a variable or a data type in C/C++ or in any other such language?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, operating-system

This is a very basic question boggling mind since the day I heard about the concept of virtual and physical memory concept in my OS class. Now I know that at load time and compile time , virtual address and logical adress binding scheme is same but at execution time they differ.

First of all why is it beneficial to generate virtual address at compile and load time and and what is returned when we apply the ampersand operator to get the address of a variable, naive datatypes , user-defined type and function definition addresses?

And how does OS maps exactly from virtual to physical address when it does so? These questions are hust out from curiosity and I would love some good and deep insights considering modern day OS' , How was it in early days OS' .I am only C/C++ specific since I don't know much about other languages.

Comment: The address of a variable is not determined at compile time... that should answer most of this.

Comment: "Now I know that at load time and compile time , virtual address is generated but at execution time physical address is generated?" -- No. If you think that, then you don't understand what virtual and physical addresses are and need to study the issue further. The answer to your question is "virtual addresses" ... that's the only kind of address programs see or deal with (except for technical exceptions involving certain systems calls on some systems).

Comment: @JimBalter: I have corrected it .

Comment: No, you haven't, you've just expressed a different confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Physical addresses occur in hardware, not software. A possible/occasional exception is in the operating system kernel. Physical means it's the address that the system bus and the RAM chips see.

Not only are physical addresses useless to software, but it could be a security issue. Being able to access any physical memory without address translation, and knowing the addresses of other processes, would allow unfettered access to the machine.

That said, smaller or embedded machines might have no virtual memory, and some older operating systems did allow shared libraries to specify their final physical memory location. Such policies hurt security and are obsolete.

Comment: Physical addresses are irrelevant to security. Access control is relevant. Every process could share one address space as long as the hardware prevented one process from accessing the memory of another process. In fact, mathematically, the combination of (process ID, virtual address) is identical to a single address space (in which the process ID is concatenated with the virtual address).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ideally, yeah, but it doesn't help when a malicious program knows where to get the stuff it shouldn't, once it has the keys to the castle. In practical terms, malware *will* get root access so it's worthwhile to de-trivialize applying patches to shared libraries.

Comment: That answer is wrong in multiple aspects. Not unyl are _virtual_ as well as _physical_ addresses processed in hardware (the program run by the CPU uses virtual addresses which are translated to physical by a hardware: the MMU. Also, physical addresses per se do not impose a security risk. They only do if there is no memory protection unit which only allows each process to access its own memroy area(s). While often combined with an MMU, for ARM Cortex-M for instance, there is no MMU, but a MPU). Relevant is that the MPU can seperately allow read/write and - best - execute.

Comment: For obsolescense: This i nonsense, as it depends on the application/firmware. If there is only one process, there might be no actual need for an MPU or even MMU. Also, the MMU costs chip ressources, which might be put to a better use (e.g. DMA). An MMU makes DMA for instance much more complicated. Note also: small embedded systems _do_ have no virtual memory as this would cost RAM space (these systems might very well only have <1KiB (e.g. MSP430, AVR, PIC) up to ~512KiB (very large MCUs, e.g. Cortex-M, PIC32, Coldfire) RAM - as of 2015.

Comment: int i=4 ; cout<<&i ; it returns 0x28ff44 , is this address of virtual memory ?

Answer (score 4):

At the application level (e.g. Linux application process), only virtual addresses exist. Local variables are on the stack (or in registers). The stack is organized in [call frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). The compiler generates the offset of a local variable within the current call frame, usually an offset relative to the stack pointer or frame pointer register (so the address of a local variable, e.g. in a recursive function, is known only at runtime).

Try to step by step a recursive function in your `gdb` debugger and display the address of some local variable to understand more. Try also the `bt` command of `gdb`.

Type

```
cat /proc/self/maps
```

to understand the address space (and [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) mapping) of the process executing that `cat` command.

Within the kernel, the mapping from virtual addresses to physical RAM is done by code implementing [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) and driving the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). Some system calls (notably [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and others) can change the address space of your process.

Some early computers (e.g. those from the 1950-s or early 1960-s like [CAB 500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAB500) or [IBM 1130](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_1130) or [IBM 1620](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_1620)) did not have any MMU, even the original [Intel 8086](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8086) didn't have any memory protection. At that time (1960-s), *C* did not exist. On processors without MMU you don't have virtual addresses (only physical ones, including in your embedded C code for a washing-machine manufacturer). Some machines could protect writing into some memory banks thru physical switches. Today, some low end cheap processors (those in washing machines) don't have any MMU. Most cheap [microcontrollers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) don't have any MMU. Often (but not always), the program is in some ROM so cannot be overwritten by buggy code.

Comment: Um, Intel 8086's didn't have MMU's, and they were produced far more recently than the 1950's. Heck, many embedded CPUs still don't have MMUs.

Comment: It was more for micro computers than for computers

Comment: Microcomputers are computers. Every desktop, laptop, tablet, and phone computer is a microcomputer.

Comment: I never understood if my micro-oven or my washing-machine is a computer or not. For me, a computer is something *I can program* (and I did program, as a teenager in a museum in the mid 1970s, both IBM1620 & CAB500). Then, my Android phone is not a computer (even if I know it is): I am too lazy to program on it....

Comment: "my Android phone is not a computer" -- I didn't say you phone is a computer ... it *contains* a computer and people can and do program them ... even you could. Many of your comments make little sense ... like the one about protecting writing with switches -- that has nothing to do with virtual addresses. Or C vs. MMU's ... it can run on machines with and without them. And I programmed IBM1620's and now computers far more powerful but much smaller -- microcomputers as they all are, like I said.

Comment: Agreed that it is not much related to MMU but in the 1960s physical switch was the only way to disable writing to some protected tracks of the magnetic drum (the RAM of the CAB500) and it was very useful: the compiler and the command interpreter was in "read-only" memory, and even a buggy program could not crash them

Comment: "Agreed that it is not much related to MMU" -- Then it doesn't belong in your answer to this question, which is about *virtual addresses*.

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is "microcontroller", which is not just a smaller chip, but also generally less powerful than a desktop computer CPU. Unlike desktop CPUs, microcontrollers have hardware peripheral circuits on-board, for example UART, CAN, analog-to-digital converters etc. Another difference more relevant to this discussion is that most of the smaller microcontrollers (8- and 16-bit) do not have a MMU, but only uses physical addresses.

Comment: On microcontrollers today, there is usually a programming mode interface which you could use to reprogram your washing machine if the chip were desoldered. But sometimes there's an option to program the chip not to allow reprogramming. Gets right to the philosophy. But functionally little different from that anti-crash switch in the ancient mainframe.