# Data type of addresses

Tags: c++, c

What is data type of any address in c or c++? Is it unsigned int or signed int?
pointers are pointing to a location of  the respective data type they point. 
It can be char or int or float anything, but what I want to ask here is what is the data type of the addresses in any language in RAM.

Comment: You mean, you want to know what the actual size and layout of a pointer is? Pointers are data types by themselves, their actual representation in bytes and bits is implementation and machine architecture dependent.

Comment: It's neither an unsigned nor a signed integer. Pointers are pointers.

Comment: It is meaningless to ask what the data type of something is in RAM. It's just a sequence of bytes, like anything else. It is how those sequences of bytes are interpreted that is important. In C++, a pointer is interpreted as a `T*`, where `T` is the type of the object it points at. What this interpretation means is defined by the C++ standard. So a pointer to `int` is an `int*` - there's nothing more to it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15654374/694576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An address is simply an integer numeric value that refers to a memory location.  The concept of a "type" is a language imposition - at the machine level addresses and data are all simply numeric (hence the term *digital* computers).

The width of an address in terms of the number of bits depends on the specific hardware architecture.

A pointer and an address are not necessarily the same thing - some architectures have paged or segmented memory addressing schemes that may mean the relationship is not that simple. 16-bit x86 for example has concepts of *near* and *far* pointers, and a segmented addressing scheme that allows for 16 or 32 bit pointers that can each resolve to a 20 bit physical address.

Answer (score 0):

An address in C is a pointer value.

Example:

```
int a = 42;
```

the address of `a` is `&a` and has type `int *`.

Answer (score 0):

Addresses have no types. It is pointers that have types that are specified when they are defined.
As for addresses then they for example can use not all bits of equivalent integer representation. For example the most significant bit of the highest byte of an address may contain some garbage. It is implementation defined what ranges of an address space can be addressed.
But in any case if you are going to reinterpret an address as some integral value then it is logically better to use unsigned types.

Answer (score 0):

Addresses are basically represented in Hexadecimal format. There is no specific data type for addresses.
To Print the address in C Language you need to use `%p` format specifier. It wont give any warnings. If you use `%u` format specifier for addresses, it will give warning.